# calcular porcentagem de itens iterados em um loop

Tags: javascript, array, loop

Como obter a porcentagem do total de itens em um array que foram processados em um loop?

Exemplo:

```
// array fictício (238 itens)
var arr = ["AF","AL","DZ","AS","AD","AO","AQ","AG","AR","AM","AW","AU","AT","AZ","BS","BH","BD","BB","BY","BE","BZ","BJ","BM","BT","BO","BA","BW","BV","BR","IO","BN","BG","BF","BI","KH","CM","CA","CV","KY","CF","TD","CL","CN","CX","CC","CO","KM","CG","CD","CK","CR","CI","HR","CU","CY","CZ","DK","DJ","DM","DO","EC","EG","SV","GQ","ER","EE","ET","FK","FO","FJ","FI","FR","GF","PF","TF","GA","GM","GE","DE","GH","GI","GR","GL","GD","GP","GU","GT","GN","GW","GY","HT","HM","HN","HK","HU","IS","IN","ID","IR","IQ","IE","IL","IT","JM","JP","JO","KZ","KE","KI","KP","KR","KW","KG","LA","LV","LB","LS","LR","LY","LI","LT","LU","MO","MK","MG","MW","MY","MV","ML","MT","MH","MQ","MR","MU","YT","MX","FM","MD","MC","MN","ME","MS","MA","MZ","MM","NA","NR","NP","NL","AN","NC","NZ","NI","NE","NG","NU","NF","MP","NO","OM","PK","PW","PS","PA","PG","PY","PE","PH","PN","PL","PT","PR","QA","RE","RO","RU","RW","SH","KN","LC","PM","VC","WS","SM","ST","SA","SN","RS","SC","SL","SG","SK","SI","SB","SO","ZA","GS","ES","LK","SD","SR","SJ","SZ","SE","CH","SY","TW","TJ","TZ","TH","TL","TG","TK","TO","TT","TN","TR","TM","TC","TV","UG","UA","AE","GB","US","UM","UY","UZ","VU","VE","VN","VG","VI","WF","EH","YE","ZM","ZW"];
//
var per = arr.length / 100;
var count = 0;
// loop
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     count++;
     // console.log(per * count - arr.length); // output 328.43999999999994
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A conta que deves fazer para ter a percentagem é `count * 100 / total`.
O código poderia ficar assim:

```js
// array fictício (238 itens)
var arr = ["AF", "AL", "DZ", "AS", "AD", "AO", "AQ", "AG", "AR", "AM", "AW", "AU", "AT", "AZ", "BS", "BH", "BD", "BB", "BY", "BE", "BZ", "BJ", "BM", "BT", "BO", "BA", "BW", "BV", "BR", "IO", "BN", "BG", "BF", "BI", "KH", "CM", "CA", "CV", "KY", "CF", "TD", "CL", "CN", "CX", "CC", "CO", "KM", "CG", "CD", "CK", "CR", "CI", "HR", "CU", "CY", "CZ", "DK", "DJ", "DM", "DO", "EC", "EG", "SV", "GQ", "ER", "EE", "ET", "FK", "FO", "FJ", "FI", "FR", "GF", "PF", "TF", "GA", "GM", "GE", "DE", "GH", "GI", "GR", "GL", "GD", "GP", "GU", "GT", "GN", "GW", "GY", "HT", "HM", "HN", "HK", "HU", "IS", "IN", "ID", "IR", "IQ", "IE", "IL", "IT", "JM", "JP", "JO", "KZ", "KE", "KI", "KP", "KR", "KW", "KG", "LA", "LV", "LB", "LS", "LR", "LY", "LI", "LT", "LU", "MO", "MK", "MG", "MW", "MY", "MV", "ML", "MT", "MH", "MQ", "MR", "MU", "YT", "MX", "FM", "MD", "MC", "MN", "ME", "MS", "MA", "MZ", "MM", "NA", "NR", "NP", "NL", "AN", "NC", "NZ", "NI", "NE", "NG", "NU", "NF", "MP", "NO", "OM", "PK", "PW", "PS", "PA", "PG", "PY", "PE", "PH", "PN", "PL", "PT", "PR", "QA", "RE", "RO", "RU", "RW", "SH", "KN", "LC", "PM", "VC", "WS", "SM", "ST", "SA", "SN", "RS", "SC", "SL", "SG", "SK", "SI", "SB", "SO", "ZA", "GS", "ES", "LK", "SD", "SR", "SJ", "SZ", "SE", "CH", "SY", "TW", "TJ", "TZ", "TH", "TL", "TG", "TK", "TO", "TT", "TN", "TR", "TM", "TC", "TV", "UG", "UA", "AE", "GB", "US", "UM", "UY", "UZ", "VU", "VE", "VN", "VG", "VI", "WF", "EH", "YE", "ZM", "ZW"];
//
var total = arr.length;
var count = 0;
// loop
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  count++;
  console.log((count * 100 / total).toFixed(2) + '%'); // output 1 - 100%
}
```

Comment: Mas se a intenção for mostrar o andamento no browser, aí complica.